# Python 3.4 Celsius To Fahrenheit

Tags: python, python-3.4

I need a USER INPUT code in python 3.4 that turns Celsius into Fahrenheit. Where the user enters a Celsius number and turns into a farhenheit degree.

Comment: First google result: http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/celsius-fahrenheit

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  We are happy to help you with any specific problems you encounter, but you need to at least attempt something before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have an input statement to start with:

```
celsius = input("Enter degrees in Celsius')
```

Then write your code for converting Celsius to Fahrenheit:

```
Celsius -> Fahrenheit:

Multiply by 9, then Divide by 5, then Add 32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Name
Name = raw_input("Enter name= ")

# Enter fDegree value
F = input("enter Fah Degree value= ")

# Calculation for cDegree
C = (5.00/9.00)*(F-32.00)`#formula`

print "The input Fdegress= {:.2f}".format(F)
print "Celsius Degree = {:.2f}".format(C)
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59640094/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

Hi this program can calculate both Fahrenheit to Celsius and Celsius to Fahrenheit. If you scroll down you will see the code for Celsius itself.

```
import time # importing functions 
start=time.perf_counter()#starting timer 
try:
    x=int(input(' 1-Fahrenheit to Celsius. 2-Celsius to Fahrenheit please enter option 
1 or 2:')) #asking for input 
    if x==1:
        a=int(input('enter the temperature in Fahrenheit')) # asking the temperature
        b=(a-32)/1.8# calculating
        print('the temperature is',b,'degrees celsius')#printing 
     elif x==2:
        c=int(input('enter the temperature in celsius'))
        d=(c*9/5)+32
        print('the temperature is ' ,d,'degrees Fahrenheit')
    else:
        print('please enter a valid option')
except Exception:
    print('please enter something valid')#error statement 
finally:
    end=time.perf_counter()#ending timer
    f=end-start
message='The time taken is %s seconds'
print(message % f)# printing time
```

The code for the Celsius itself:

```
c=int(input('enter the temperature in Celsius'))
d=(c*9/5)+32
print('the temperature is ' ,d,'degrees Fahrenheit')
```

Please let me know if you have any questions 
Anikait Sota

Comment: You are very kind, but SO is not the place for this type of question, which can easily be found on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Input Statement

```
celsius = float(input('Enter temperature in Celsius: '))
```

code for convert it to Fahrenheit

```
fahrenheit = (celsius * 1.8) + 32.
```

print output

```
print('%0.1f Celsius is equal to %0.1f degree Fahrenheit'%(celsius,fahrenheit))
```